# Is it possible to have nested user defined controls in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working with Expression Blend 3.  I want to do something and I do not know if it is possible but common sense tells me it should be.

The whole idea is to break apart a XAML content into three XAML pages.  One page is the master that contains controls defined in two seperate pages.  That is it.  Can it be done?

Comment: Of course...... Why don't you just try it first and then ask a specific question when the implementation goes wrong? You've been registered on SO for 6 years, yet you ask a question "can it be done?"... How's that possible?

Comment: I just figured it out by adding this to the controls to be nested:

Comment: xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
 xmlns:SWECommonControls="clr-namespace:SWECommonControls;assembly=SWECommonControls"

Comment: so, yeah, I am going to remove this question

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the child controls to be nested:

```
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
xmlns:SWECommonControls="clr-namespace:SWECommonControls;assembly=SWECommonControls"
```